# Import pre-build objectbox db

Tags: android, database, objectbox

I have a pre-build `SQLITE` DB in my project.
I would like to convert my old DB to `Objectbox`.

1. Is it possible to create a pre-build `Objectbox` db?
2. If so, how can I use the pre-build db if I already use a `BoxStoreBuilder` of another db (`Objectbox` also) in the same project?

Comment: See here: https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/292#issuecomment-349223960

Answer (score 2):

1) Sure, in v. 1.4.4 added for BoxStoreBuilder.initialDbFile(...) which will provide a initial data file if it does not exist before.
Example:

```
companion object {
    const val INITIAL_DB = "data.mdb"
}

private var inputStreamFactory: Factory<InputStream> = Factory { context.resources.assets.open(INITIAL_DB) }

private val box: BoxStore by lazy {
    MyObjectBox.builder().initialDbFile(inputStreamFactory).androidContext(context).build()
}
```

Where `data.mdb` placed in your assets folder.

As far as I know this `data.mdb` file works across plaforms (x64, ARM, 32 and 64 bit)

2)I think you have to transfer data manually in some way.